# Execute external command and exchange variable using Python

Tags: python, linux, loops, terminal, netcdf

#### 1. Introduction

I have a bunch of files in **netcdf** format.
Each file contain the meteorology condition of somewhere in different period(hourly data).
I need to extract the first 12 h data for each file. So I select to use NCO(netcdf operator) to deal with.

**NCO** works with terminal environment. With `>ncks -d Time 0,11 input.nc output.nc`, I can get one datafile called `out.nc`which contain the first 12h data of `in.nc`.

#### 2. My attempt

I want to keep all the process inside my ipython notebook. But I stuck on two aspects.

> 1. How to execute terminal code in python loop
> 2. How to transfer the string in python into terminal code.

Here is my fake code for example.

```
files = os.listdir('.')
for file in files:
    filename,extname = os.path.splitext(file)
    if extname == '.nc':   
        output = filename + "_0-12_" + extname
        ## The code below was my attempt
        !ncks -d Time 0,11 file output`
```

#### 3. Conclusion

Basically, my target was letting the fake code `!ncks -d Time 0,11 file output` coming true.  That means:

1. execute netcdf operator directly in python loop...
2. ...using `filename` which is an string in python environment.

Sorry for my unclear question. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: "`...input.nc output.nc`, I can get one datafile called **out.nc** which contain the first 12h data of **in.nc**" can I assume this inconsistency of files is a typo?

Comment: have you looked at [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?module-os#os.system), [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) and [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html?highlight=sys.argv#sys.argv)?

Comment: I tried `os.system("my command here")` and `subprocess.call([])`. They all failed to achieve.

Comment: I meant did you look at the documentation, `subprocess.call` won't let you just use `ncks` without specifying the full path or `shell=True`

Comment: Thanks for you comments! I have tried `subprocess.call` and `subprocess.check_output` in ipython notebook environment. The second one works. But they all works well in python console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) to execute external program:

```
import glob
import subprocess

for fn in glob.iglob('*.nc'):
    filename, extname = os.path.splitext(fn)
    output_fn = filename + "_0-12_" + extname
    output = subprocess.call(['ncks', '-d', 'Time', '0,11', fn, output_fn])
    print(output)
```

NOTE: updated the code to use [`glob.iglob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.iglob); you don't need to check extension manually.

Comment: you could've used `files = glob('*.nc')`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already try it, but it seems not working.

Comment: @NizamMohamed, Thank you for your comment. I updated the code to use `glob.iglob`.

Comment: @HanZhengzu, How does it not work? It would be nice if you give more detail.

Comment: For a test, directly using `subprocess.call(['ncks', '-d', 'Time', '0,11', "test.nc", "output.nc"])`. The python console return `> 1`. But using `!ncks -d Time,0,11 test.nc output.nc ` works.

Comment: @HanZhengzu, Try these: (1) Replace `ncks` with `!ncks` . (2) Replace `ncks` with its absolute path (you can get the absolute path of it using `which ncks` (2') Replace `ncks` with absolute path of `!ncks` (if `!` is the part of the executable's name)

Comment: ''!" is not the part of this commander. I use `!` when execute terminal code(like `ls -a`) as a start character in python.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107235/discussion-between-han-zhengzu-and-falsetru).

Answer (score 2):

You may also check out [pynco](http://pynco.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#examples) which wraps the NCO with subprocess calls, similar to @falsetru's answer. Your application may look something like

```
nco = Nco()
for fn in glob.iglob('*.nc'):
    filename, extname = os.path.splitext(fn)
    output_fn = filename + "_0-12_" + extname
    nco.ncks(input=filename, output=output_fn, dimension='Time 0,11')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!